# when you click on of the item, it should take you to other screen, but error on if condition?

Tags: android

```
package com.example.Calc;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class modes extends ListActivity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
        String[] names = new String[] { "Simple Calculator", "Tip Calculator", "Mortgage Calculator", "BMI",
                "GPA Calculator"};
        // Create an ArrayAdapter, that will actually make the Strings above
        // appear in the ListView
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        string content;
        if( content ="Simple Calculator")
        {
             // When clicked, Open the Next Screen
             Intent r=new Intent(modes.this ,simplecalculator.class );
        }
    }
}
```

**Getting error on if( content ="simple calculator")
I want when i click simple calculator it should take me to other screen.. i have defined everything, but i forgot the if condition thing.. everything is done.. its just whats the condition for if..
please help and thanks for your time.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    String content = ((ArrayAdapter<String>)l.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
    if( content.equals("Simple Calculator"))
    {
         // When clicked, Open the Next Screen
         Intent r=new Intent(this ,simplecalculator.class );
         startActivity(r);
    }
}
```

A few things:

1) Please use CamelCase for your class names.

2) String starts with a captial letter (as *should* all Java classes).

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `if (content.equals("Simple Calculator"))`, not `if (content = "Simple Calculator")`

Comment: sorry for not accepting because  his answer was more proper and detailed :)